# Centering flexbox layout without using justify-content:center;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center all the contents in my `flex-container` vertically in the middle of my page but I can't seem to get it to work. The only thing that made sense to me was to change the `justify-content:flex-wrap` to `justify-content:center`, but I cant do that because then it messes with my images being wrapped properly. Any other suggestion on how I can center the contents in my `flex-container`? Anything helps, thanks.

```css
/*Fonts*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css);

/*Body*/
body {
 font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 padding-bottom: 3rem;}

/*Profile Picture*/
.profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.image {
  background-image: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1');}

/*Profile Name*/
.profile-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-20px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  font-weight:bold;}

/*User Name*/
.user-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-30px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  color:rgba(1,1,1,0.35);}

/*Follow Button*/
.follow-button-position {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:55px;
  margin-top:-10px;}
.follow-button {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:7.5px;
  padding-bottom:7.5px; 
  padding-left:25px; 
  padding-right:25px;
  border-radius:2px;
  background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0); 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#af985a; 
  border-width:1px;
  color:#af985a;}
.follow-button:hover {
  cursor:pointer;}

/*Posts*/
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;}

img {
    max-width:270px;
  height:auto;
padding:15px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="profile-picture image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
  <p>cole gwoz</p> 
</div>

<div class="user-name">
  <p>colegwoz</p>
</div>

<div class="follow-button-position">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Lol what was wrong with my answer?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I needed to rephrase my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your profile image centering as well. Maybe I'm not understanding the question? Can you provide screenshots of what it currently looks like and what you want it to look like? The container can be centered, but with the way you are setting a `max-width` on the images, it is causing them to not be centered in the container. Do you just want a way to make sure your images are centered on the page in two columns? Should the columns grow with the screen size?

```css
/*Fonts*/

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css);

/*Body*/

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}


/*Profile Picture*/

.profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 55px auto 35px auto;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1');
}


/*Profile Name*/

.profile-name {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*User Name*/

.user-name {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.35);
}


/*Follow Button*/

.follow-button-position {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.follow-button {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7.5px;
  padding-bottom: 7.5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #af985a;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #af985a;
}

.follow-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Posts*/

.img-cont {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 900px;
    min-width: 950px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  max-width: 270px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="profile-picture image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
  <p>cole gwoz</p>
</div>

<div class="user-name">
  <p>colegwoz</p>
</div>

<div class="follow-button-position">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>

<div class="flex-container img-cont">
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>

  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>

  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>

  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>

  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: When you resize the screen the posts don't always stay centered. https://imgur.com/JlqafGJ

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki I updated my answer, please try again

Comment: Your updated response messes with the alignment of the images when they fall down. I'm trying to achive something like this: http://vsco.co/colegwoz/images/1 all the images stay aligned in columns and in the center of the page no matter how the screen is resized. Also the padding is all the same, but your updated code messes with the alignment and padding.

Comment: Man, are you asking multiple questions in one? We're all confused as to what you want! Can you find an example of what you want or a mockup or something? It's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear, I just linked an example so it can help understand more. I'm adding the max width to the images so there all the same width size like on the VSCO page I linked.

Comment: Ah okay, you are trying to get that pinterest "collage" look? That's a very different question than what you have asked here.

Comment: Yes exactly. Oh no, I might have to rephrase my questions again then.

Comment: Updated my answer. Closer to what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes exactly, except it got rid of the responsive collapsing I originally had.

Comment: Not sure what "got rid of the responsive collapsing I originally had" means. I made a new answer that copies exactly what you posted with only one minor change.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is exactly what you posted with only the `flex-direction` change to achieve the pinterest "collage" layout. One caveat when using this layout, it only works if the container has a **fixed height**. Infinite scrolling and dynamically added images won't work without some JS code to resize the parent:

```css
/*Fonts*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css);

/*Body*/
body {
 font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 padding-bottom: 3rem;}

/*Profile Picture*/
.profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.image {
  background-image: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1');}

/*Profile Name*/
.profile-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-20px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  font-weight:bold;}

/*User Name*/
.user-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-30px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  color:rgba(1,1,1,0.35);}

/*Follow Button*/
.follow-button-position {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:55px;
  margin-top:-10px;}
.follow-button {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:7.5px;
  padding-bottom:7.5px; 
  padding-left:25px; 
  padding-right:25px;
  border-radius:2px;
  background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0); 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#af985a; 
  border-width:1px;
  color:#af985a;}
.follow-button:hover {
  cursor:pointer;}

/*Posts*/
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;}

img {
    max-width:270px;
  height:auto;
padding:15px;}

.img-cont {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="profile-picture image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
  <p>cole gwoz</p> 
</div>

<div class="user-name">
  <p>colegwoz</p>
</div>

<div class="follow-button-position">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>

<div class="flex-container img-cont">
  <div>
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: center;` will do it. For flex-wrap it's `flex-wrap: wrap;`

If this isn't working for you, you can add a media query and switch the flex-container to `flex-direction: column;` and add `align-items: center;`

Comment: Like I said, using the justify-content:center; removes my wrap around the images so I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

just add css .flex-container > div{margin:0 auto}

```css
/*Fonts*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css);

/*Body*/
body {
 font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 padding-bottom: 3rem;}

/*Profile Picture*/
.profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.image {
  background-image: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1');}

/*Profile Name*/
.profile-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-20px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  font-weight:bold;}

/*User Name*/
.user-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-30px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  color:rgba(1,1,1,0.35);}

/*Follow Button*/
.follow-button-position {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:55px;
  margin-top:-10px;}
.follow-button {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:7.5px;
  padding-bottom:7.5px; 
  padding-left:25px; 
  padding-right:25px;
  border-radius:2px;
  background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0); 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#af985a; 
  border-width:1px;
  color:#af985a;}
.follow-button:hover {
  cursor:pointer;}

/*Posts*/
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;}
.flex-container > div{
margin:0 auto;
}
img {
    max-width:270px;
  height:auto;
padding:15px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="profile-picture image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
  <p>cole gwoz</p> 
</div>

<div class="user-name">
  <p>colegwoz</p>
</div>

<div class="follow-button-position">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: That messes up my images being wrapped so they align in a column